# Incorrect calculation by strlen for a string pointer?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char *str3;
    str3="Final string.";
    for(;*str3;)
    {
        printf("%c", *str3++);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d bytes", strlen(str3));

    return 0;
}
```

I've been confused about why the output says `0 bytes` when it *should* be saying `13 bytes`. I removed the `for` loop like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char *str3;
    str3="Final string.";
    printf("%d bytes", strlen(str3));
    return 0;
}
```

and the output comes out correct saying `13 bytes`. So I figured it had something to do with the `for` loop. My guess was: The loop reads through the contents but updates the variable as it goes along i.e. `*str3++`, once it's complete there's no data left to read and all the data that was already read is, well, *read & gone* (hehe)... which means `0 bytes`?? Like reading a book and whiting out the last word you read.

If that's the case I'd have to refill it with data, do a repeat initialization by putting `str3="Final string.";` directly after the for loop and it'll show the correct output...but...I feel like that's a bad/cheap trick?

I'm not exactly sure what's happening. Please help.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: str3++ will increment the pointer until it points to the end of the string, hence the length will be 0.

Comment: To avoid that, make a copy of said pointer and make your loop use it instead.

Comment: Because you moved the pointer to point at the null terminator at the end of the string. If you tell a pointer to point somewhere else, then surprise, it will start pointing somewhere else.

Comment: Add the statement `printf(“s3 = %p\nstrlen(s3) = %zu\n”, (void *) s3, strlen(s3) );` to your `for` loop, and it should be clear what’s happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before `for` loop, `str3` is pointing to:

```
str3
 |
 V
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+--+ 
|F|i|n|a|l| |s|t|r|i|n|g|.|\0|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+--+
```

In `for` loop you are incrementing `str3` in `printf()` till `str3` hits null-character:

```
printf("%c", *str3++);
```

So, after for loop `str3` is pointing to:

```
                          str3
                           |
                           V
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+--+ 
|F|i|n|a|l| |s|t|r|i|n|g|.|\0|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+--+
```

`strlen()` determines the length of a string by terminating null-character. Since `str3` is pointing to terminating null-character of string, hence you are getting the output `0`.

You can take another pointer and point it to `str3` and use it in `for` loop, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char *str3, *tmp;
    str3="Final string.";
    tmp=str3;
    for(;*tmp;)
    {
        printf("%c", *tmp++);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%zu bytes", strlen(str3));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Final string.
13
```

---

Additional:

`strlen()` return type is `size_t`. You should use format specifier `%zu` for printing the `strlen` returned value.

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing the `str` pointer until it points to `0` (the end of the string) and when you call `strlen(str3)` it returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

you are advancing the pointer to the start (initialization)of the string until it points to the end of the string. Hence when you call strlen on it you get size 0 - at that point it already points to the end of the string
you should use an auxillary pointer to iterate the string - advance it while iterating while the `strlen` command will be with the original `str3`

you can also add a counter in your `for` body and that will save you the need to call `strlen` at the end

in your case the string is literal and does not need to be freed, but when the strings are dynamically allocated working with an auxillary pointer is a must. - you must free allocated memory with the original  pointer (returned from the allocation)